# Difference Between Views and Tables in Performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, view

What is best for tables with a lot of data?

I have a stored procedure that creates a report based on some filters. In my SP I read the table and put all the inner joins and formulas then in the where condition I put the filters.

Talking about performance what's better?

Create a view with all the joins OR read the table (as I'm doing)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Performance is a lot more dependent on having the appropriate indexes than if you are using a view or direct table access, which (except for materialized views) behave exactly the same way.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

As long as the View does not contain aggregations (or constructs that require materialisation 'upfront'), it will be exactly the same performance (and in many cases can pass through where criteria with shortcircuiting by the optimiser)

Have you tried benchmarking in your specific cases?

@Otávio Décio beat me to it, by mentioning that having the 'correct' indexes will have a greater effect on performance.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `select count(*) from view` it will significantly slow than table. Because the table contains row number on its header, a view doesn't have such information.